# Check if all array items are of the same constructor [lodash]

Tags: javascript, lodash

Let's say we have a class:

```
class MyClass {
    constructor() {
        this.prop1 = 1;
        this.prop2 = 2;
        this.whatever = 3;
    }
}
```

and two collections:

```
arr1 = [new MyClass(), new MyClass(), new MyClass()];
arr2 = [new MyClass(), new MyClass(), "notMyClassObject"];
```

The question is:

Does lodash have methods to detect if all items in collection are of the same constructor?

Expected result:

```
_.isArrayOf(arr1, MyClass) // => true
_.isArrayOf(arr2, MyClass) // => false
```

## EDIT

Question extension (case 2):

Let's say we have an inherited class:

```
class MyChildClass extends MyClass {
    constructor() {
        this.childProp1 = 4
    }
}
```

and collections:

```
arr1 = [new MyClass(), new MyChildClass(), new MyClass()];
arr2 = [new MyClass(), new MyChildClass(), "notMyClassObject"]
```

expected results:

```
_.isArrayOf(arr1, MyClass) // => true
_.isArrayOf(arr2, MyClass) // => false
```

Answer (score 5):

This is trivial with vanilla JS's `Array.prototype.every`, no library needed:

```js
class MyClass {
    constructor() {
        this.prop1 = 1;
        this.prop2 = 2;
        this.whatever = 3;
    }
}

const arr1 = [new MyClass(), new MyClass(), new MyClass()];
const arr2 = [new MyClass(), new MyClass(), "notMyClassObject"];

console.log(arr1.every(i => i.constructor === MyClass));
console.log(arr2.every(i => i.constructor === MyClass));
```

Feel free to use lodash for it if you want to, though:

```js
class MyClass {
    constructor() {
        this.prop1 = 1;
        this.prop2 = 2;
        this.whatever = 3;
    }
}

const arr1 = [new MyClass(), new MyClass(), new MyClass()];
const arr2 = [new MyClass(), new MyClass(), "notMyClassObject"];

console.log(_.every(arr1, i => i.constructor === MyClass));
console.log(_.every(arr2, i => i.constructor === MyClass));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.core.min.js"></script>
```

The `.constructor` check will check that the item being iterated over was created with `new MyClass()` - to include subclasses as well, use `instanceof`:

```js
class MyClass {
    constructor() {
        this.prop1 = 1;
        this.prop2 = 2;
        this.whatever = 3;
    }
}
class Child extends MyClass {
}

const arr1 = [new MyClass(), new Child(), new MyClass()];
const arr2 = [new MyClass(), new MyClass(), "notMyClassObject"];

console.log(arr1.every(i => i instanceof MyClass));
console.log(arr2.every(i => i instanceof MyClass));
```

Comment: this method is good when there is no class inheritance (my bad, didn't mentioned about inheritance)

Comment: `.constructor` is intentionally very specific, to permit subclasses, use `instanceof`

Answer (score 2):

Lodash doesn't have such method but you can always use `every` this way:

```
_.every([new MyClass(), new MyClass(), new MyClass()], i => i.constructor === MyClass);
```